# Php date move to next month

Tags: php

I'm trying to write a PHP code that's a bit complex for me...

I'd like when data is posted to my PHP file it check the today date and if the current date if after the fifth of the month, the code will echo the fifth of next month.
Like :

```
$today = "2018-04-24";
if(today>5){
echo "2018-05-05";
}
```

I hope I'm making myself comprehensible.

Thanks

Comment: For future postings please look at https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks

Comment: Are you saying that no matter the date, you alway want move to the next nearest 5th of the month?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need a proper date handling to handle edge cases like `2018-12-24`.

```
$today = "2018-03-31";

$dt = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d', $today);
$d = intval($dt->format('j'));

if($d > 5) {
  $dt->setDate($dt->format('Y'), $dt->format('n'), 5);
  $dt->add(new DateInterval('P1M'));
}

echo $dt->format('Y-m-d');
```

Comment: This is still prone to error (eg. `2018-03-31` +1 month would result in `2018-05-01`, it'd be better to set the day to the 5th before adding a month, since 5th +1 month is always the 5th of the following month).. dates are a pain

Comment: Awsome ! Thank !

Comment: @billyonecan I didn't think about that! Fixed now. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

```
function get_month_diff($start, $end = FALSE){
$end OR $end = time();
$start = new DateTime("@$start");
$end   = new DateTime("@$end");
$diff  = $start->diff($end);
return $diff->format('%y') * 12 + $diff->format('%m');}
```

Comment: get month and use them as you want

Answer (score 0):

you can do like this

```
 $today = date('Y-m-d');
    $exploded_date = explode('-',$today);
    if($exploded_date[2] > 5){
     echo date('Y-m-05', strtotime("+1 months", strtotime($today)));
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

After the fifth of the month, the code will echo the fifth of next month, you can use this :

```
$effectiveDate = "2018-02-06";

if(date('d') > 5) {
       $effectiveDate = date('Y-m-d', strtotime("+5 months", strtotime($effectiveDate)));
}
```